# Sort dictionary whose value is in the form of list of dictionary

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, sorting, dictionary

Sorting a dictionary whose value is in the form of list of dictionary.

I have something like:

```
myDict = {'First' :[{'Name':'Raj','Date':'28-March-2019 09:30'}], 
          'Second':[{'Name':'Ajay','Date':'12-April-2020 07:25'}], 
          'Third':[{'Name':'Jaya','Date':'12-April-2019 09:25'}]}
```

I want to sort this in ascending order based on Date.

Expected output:

```
myDict = {'First' :[{'Name':'Raj','Date':'28-March-2019 09:30'}], 
          'Third' :[{'Name':'Jaya','Date':'12-April-2019 09:25'}],
          'Second':[{'Name':'Ajay','Date':'12-April-2020 07:25'}]}
```

I want the output in the form of dictionary

Comment: you can use collections.OrderedDict, or do you want a list with all the values sorted?

Comment: I want the output in the form of dictionary only

Comment: Can you the exact expected output ?

Comment: What did you try to sort and output it? [mre]? What went wrong? Your dates are text, not datetimes- and as for the date format:it is not possible to sort it just by string comparison.How do you transform it so it is comparable? Why are your values list of dictionaries if they all only have 1 dict inside - could there be more then 1 inside? If more then 1 inside, which date to use to sort by?

Comment: Does each value list only have one dictionary or can it have multiple (i.e. you only show single dictionaries in list)?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `collections.OrderedDict` with the build-in function `sorted`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from datetime import datetime

OrderedDict(sorted(myDict.items(), key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[1][0]['Date'], '%d-%B-%Y %H:%M')))
```

this solution assumes that each value from `myDict` is a list with one dict inside which has  a valid `'Date'` key (as your provided data shows)

in python2.7  dictionary insertion order it is not guaranteed, so you can't get your desired output, still, you can use OrderedDict

output:

```
OrderedDict([('First', [{'Name': 'Raj', 'Date': '28-March-2019 09:30'}]),
             ('Third', [{'Name': 'Jaya', 'Date': '12-April-2019 09:25'}]),
             ('Second', [{'Name': 'Ajay', 'Date': '12-April-2020 07:25'}])])
```

you can read more about `OrderedDict` [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

I encourage you to use [python3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6) or a higher version where you can benefit from the insertion order in a `dict`

Comment: What about multiple inner dicts? you only sort by the first dict in the list of inner dicts. question is unclear.

Comment: well sure, the OP may add details, but at least I can help with the provided data